# Folder.CopyHere() from IShellDispatch silently fails to unpack most of a Zip file, but only if the file is on a DVD

Tags: com, unzip, windows-shell, dvd

My application (the [Endless OS installer for Windows](https://endlessos.com/download/)) uses methods on [IShellDispatch (provided by Shell32.dll)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537707(v=vs.85).aspx), to extract a Zip file ([example](https://d2anzknqnc1kmb.cloudfront.net/release/3.3.4/eos-amd64-amd64/base/eos-eos3.3-amd64-amd64.171122-232702.base.boot.zip)). In various modes of operation, this file may be downloaded from the internet to a fixed disk; on an exFAT filesystem on a USB stick; or in an ISO 9660 (with Joliet extensions) image which may be mounted as a virtual drive, or written to a DVD. In all cases but the last, extracting the Zip file works; but when the Zip file is on a DVD, all that's created in the target directory is the directory structure (`EFI\BOOT\`) for the first file in the archive (`EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi`); neither that file, nor any other files in that directory or any other directory, are extracted. With *exactly the same Zip file* on any other medium — including inserting the ISO into a VirtualBox virtual optical drive — the problem disappears.

The original C++ code where I first saw this problem is [here](https://github.com/endlessm/rufus/blob/db803bf57bb6a5336008cadd10066c82c10deefe/src/endless/EndlessUsbToolDlg.cpp#L5091-L5098). It looks like this (with error handling removed, since all methods return a successful `HRESULT` in my testing, and the `FOF_NO_UI` also removed in case that was masking an error message):

```cpp
void UnpackZip(const CComBSTR source, const CComBSTR dest) {
    CComPtr<IShellDispatch>    pISD;
    CComPtr<Folder>            pToFolder, pFromFolder;
    CComPtr<FolderItems>       folderItems;

    CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Shell, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IShellDispatch,
        (void **)&pISD);
    pISD->NameSpace(CComVariant(dest), &pToFolder);
    pISD->NameSpace(CComVariant(source), &pFromFolder);
    pFromFolder->Items(&folderItems);
    pToFolder->CopyHere(CComVariant(folderItems), CComVariant(0));
}
```

I can reproduce this problem both by attempting to unpack the Zip file from Windows Explorer GUI (which does not report any errors), and by running the following in PowerShell, so I am reasonably sure it's not my application code that's at fault:

```
PS> $shell = new-object -ComObject shell.application
PS> $zip = $shell.NameSpace("D:\endless\eos-eos3.3-amd64-amd64.171122-232702.base.boot.zip")
PS> $target = $shell.NameSpace("C:\test")
PS> $target.CopyHere($zip.items())
```

If I explicitly iterate over the top-level folders in the Zip file, as follows, then some but not all files from each folder are extracted (and still none in `EFI\BOOT\`):

```
PS> foreach ($item in $zip.items()) { $target.CopyHere($item) }
```

If I explicitly select that first file which is not unpacked, no error is raised:

```
PS> $item = $zip.items().Item(0).GetFolder().Items().Item(0).GetFolder().Items().item(0);
PS> $item
Application  : System.__ComObject
Parent       : System.__ComObject
Name         : bootx64.efi
Path         :
GetLink      :
GetFolder    :
IsLink       : False
IsFolder     : False
IsFileSystem : False
IsBrowsable  : False
ModifyDate   : 22/11/2017 23:33:56
Size         : 1157984
Type         : EFI File
PS> $target.CopyHere($item)
```

But it's still not unpacked to `$target`. The DVD drive does not even spin up!

If I copy *exactly the same Zip file* to a fixed drive – or mount the DVD ISO as a virtual disk, whether within Windows, or from the outside via the VirtualBox VM Windows is running in – everything works correctly. The problem *only* occurs when the archive is really on a physical DVD. I've received many reports of this problem from users with various hardware, so it's not my DVD drive or laptop. I personally have only tested and reproduced it on Windows 10 (build 14393 and 15063, at least); I'm not sure whether it can be reproduced on older Windows versions but since Windows 10 is the most commonly-used version by users of this application, it's a moot point whether this worked on older versions.

The files which are not unpacked are all those ending `.efi` (EFI executables) and those ending `.mod` (legacy BIOS GRUB modules). This is totally deterministic. But I'm stumped as to why the shell would take such a disliking to certain files, only when the archive is on a DVD.

My application can work around this problem by copying the Zip file to the hard disk before extracting it. But the question remains: why is this happening? And at a higher level: short of stepping through the compiled Shell32.dll code in a debugger, how could I diagnose what's going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to use IFileOperation::CopyItems instead? the Folder interface was designed for automation clients (scripts, etc.). IFileOperations is the low level thing, and has a thorough callback mechanism with IFileOperationProgressSink. That being said, a shell API will more or less behave the same as when a user invokes the UI. If it doesn't work with the UI, it doesn't smell good.